# Standard ML: Size of binary tree computed incorrectly?

Tags: functional-programming, sml

My book has the following function which calculates the number of non-leaf nodes in a binary tree:

```
fun size Empty = 0 
    | size(Node(t_1, _, t_2)) = size t_1 + size t_2 + 1;
```

Suppose I want to calculate *all* nodes in a binary tree.  How would I modify this function to do so?

Here's what I was thinking:

```
fun size Empty = 0
    | size(Node(Empty, _, Empty)) = 1
    | size(Node(t_1, _, t_2)) = size t_1 + size t_2 + 1;
```

Does this look right?

Thanks,

bclayman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of the implementations that you provided are actually the same.  The second case of your second implementation is a special case of you your third pattern.  For your first implementation, `size(Node(Empty,1,Empty))` will recurse one the left subtree, returning 0, recurse on the right subtree, which returns 0, and then adds 1, yielding the result 1.  In fact, if you switch the order of the second and third case, the compiler will tell you that it is redundant:

```
test.sml:3.5-5.38 Error: match redundant
      Empty => ...
      Node (t_1,_,t_2) => ...
-->   Node (Empty,_,Empty) => ...
```

Comment: but switching the order changes the function, right?  And my function will return 3 in the case you give...

Comment: Switching the order changes the function in that it doesn't compile because of the redundant match error.  The SMLNJ REPL gives me `1` for the example that I gave, `size(Node(Empty,1,Empty))`, for both of your implementations.

Comment: Ah, so then how might I change it to count all nodes?  Thanks again!

Comment: Change your `Empty` case to return 1, this will give you 3 in my example

Answer (score 1):

Matt is correct that your two functions are functionally the same -- both of which return a count of *all* nodes in the tree. I didn't notice this at first since I took it at face value that your first function counted *nonleaf* nodes and then noticed that your `Node(Empty,_,Empty)` pattern is the correct pattern of a leaf (if a leaf is defined as a node with no non-empty children). But -- this means that the function in the book doesn't just count nonleaf (parents) nodes. If you do want a function which just counts parent nodes, there is a use for your pattern after all:

```
fun parents Empty = 0
    | parents(Node(Empty, _, Empty)) = 0
    | parents(Node(t_1, _, t_2)) = parents t_1 + parents t_2 + 1;
```

If your application of trees is one in which heavy use is made of the parent node vs. leaf node distinction, you could (at the cost of making some of your function definitions more involved) ditch the `Node` constructor in favor of separate `Parent` and `Leaf` constructors. Something like:

```
datatype 'a tree = Empty | Leaf of 'a | Parent of 'a tree * 'a * 'a tree;
```

Then you can write functions like

```
fun countLeaves Empty = 0
    | countLeaves (Leaf _) = 1
    | countLeaves (Parent(t1,_,t2)) = countLeaves t1 + countLeaves t2;
```

So e.g.

```
- val t = Parent(Parent(Leaf "2", "*", Leaf "3"), "+", Leaf "4");
- countLeaves t;
val it = 3 : int
```